# Exporting Siebel ListView

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-8, applet, siebel

I've been for the past few days trying to automate Siebel Web with Excel VBA.
With a combination of sendkeys and some webscraping, I've managed to query my data. The thing is that now I can't call the export applet in order to save it. I've searched almost every site that contains the tags "Siebel", "javascript", with no luck. Since IE developer tools are locked, I've used VBA to scrape the webpage, and tried to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), again, with no luck.

I was wondering if someone managed to export data from Siebel into a xml/csv/excel file through automation.

I'll post my code later, in order to see if you could help me.

Comment: If you were to post the code later, why question now? Take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you would be better off using one of the Siebel API's for Java or COM. The [COM interface](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/OIRef/OIRefProgramming24.html) allows you to directly integrate with Siebel using Excel VBA. It is a commonly used interface for extracting and updating business data.

It allows full access to the business layer, which includes the data sources, but also the process objects like Work Flows, Business Scripts, and other application functionality. It is truly powerful when you start working with it.

Keep in mind that you do need to be able to access the object manager port (2321) from the machine that the Excel file is running. In many corporate environment this is not allowed. So verify that you can beforehand.